# Switch first and last elements of two lists in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

In Python, I have two lists that either have equal number of elements (e.g. 8 and 8) or one less than the other (e.g. 7 and 8; 3 and 4):

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
list2 = ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
```

or

```
list3 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list4 = ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to build an algorithm that will switch the last half of the first list with the first half of the last list, resulting in this, when both lists have an even number of elements:

```
switched_list1 = ['A', 'B', 'E', 'F']
switched_list2 = ['C', 'D', 'G', 'H']
```

…and this when the one of the lists has an odd number:

```
switched_list3 = ['A', 'D', 'E']
switched_list4 = ['B', 'C', 'F', 'G']
```

What's the most efficient way to build an algorithm that can switch list elements like this?

Comment: @Marcin I think you want http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ for answers to that question; for the purposes of this question, it doesn't matter whether and/or why it's problematic.

Comment: @urschrei as the OP doesn't give even the obvious way of coding this as a start and as the OP has already a good reputation, I understand Marcin is wondering if there is something hidden on that question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make the problematicness more clear. I probably should have tagged this as Pythonic and explained it a little better. The problem is that I was trying to figure out a faster, more efficient way to switch positions instead of using temporary variables, like joaquin's answer. I had done something similar but was frustrated with how many lines of code it took. Hence the (unfortunately unstated) problem... :(

Comment: @Andrew, You may wan't to take a look at my update in my post and see if that qualifies to be pythonic and efficient or is it the same class as problematic :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> def StrangeSwitch(list1,list2):
    return (list1[:len(list1)/2]+list2[:len(list2)/2],list1[len(list1)/2:]+list2[len(list2)/2:])

>>> list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> list2 = ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
>>> (list1,list2)=StrangeSwitch(list1,list2)
>>> list1
['A', 'B', 'E', 'F']
>>> list2
['C', 'D', 'G', 'H']
>>> list3 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> list4 = ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
>>> (list3,list4)=StrangeSwitch(list3,list4)
>>> list3
['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> list4
['B', 'C', 'F', 'G']
>>>
```

Reading the Comments by OP I would take the priviledge of proposing another approach

```
>>> def StrangeSwitchFast(list1,list2):
    #return (list1[:len(list1)/2]+list2[:len(list2)/2],list1[len(list1)/2:]+list2[len(list2)/2:])
    return (list(itertools.chain(itertools.islice(list1,0,len(list1)/2),itertools.islice(list2,0,len(list2)/2))),
        list(itertools.chain(itertools.islice(list1,len(list1)/2,None),itertools.islice(list2,len(list2)/2,None))))
```

The above doesn't create any temporary list and if OP desires to use it as an iterator rather than a list for the downstream processing, then the list can be safely dropped from the function and can be left to return as a tuple of iterators.

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list2 = ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G']

nlist1 = len(list1)/2
nlist2 = len(list2)/2

new1 = list1[:nlist1] + list2[:nlist2]
new2 = list1[nlist1:] + list2[nlist2:]

print new1
print new2
```

produces

```
['A', 'D', 'E']
['B', 'C', 'F', 'G']
```